# Swap values with XOR

Tags: c#, xor

This is a valid way to swap values in C++ and in C#.

```
X ^= Y;
Y ^= X;
X ^= Y;
```

And this is a valid way to swap values in C++.

```
X ^= Y ^= X ^= Y;
```

But why is this not working in C# ?

Comment: What isn't working? How do you use it?

Comment: What error is the compiler giving you?

Comment: @Lorek No compiler error, it just doesn't swap the values.

Comment: I think if you give an example you'll get more traction.  I for one am interested in why the separate expressions work, but the stacked one does not.

Comment: Given `x=5` and `y=6` the first statements switch the values, the second statement makes `x=0` and `y=5`. Have a look here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/K3QBtL

Comment: @rcgldr I had the same thought, but this `x ^= (y ^= (x ^= y));` also doesn't 
"work".  Actually assignment operators are [right to left]( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx) and I don't see how they could be otherwise.

Comment: The second is not a valid way to swap values(or do anything else) in C++. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: Besides the "does it work" or not, it's a "fun party trick that is completely useless in real life". Code written like this is significantly slower  [expect 2-3x slower or worse, because of the immediate dependency of the values] than the `temp = x; x = y; y = temp;` solution [which also works for float, double, pointer, objects, structures, etc, etc, instead of just integer types]

Comment: As Benjamin points out, with warning level set to all, GCC warns that the one liner "may be undefined behavior", while Microsoft compilers don't give any warning. However the code works for both GCC and Microsoft compilers, so although undefined behavior in the standard, it's not undefined behavior for specific compilers.

Comment: In C++, we better swap with `std::swap`. No reason to waste time with unreadable code like the "xor-trick" or even by using temporary variables.

Comment: @rcgldr: Testing it out and appearing to work is not a reliable way to see if something is undefined behavior. It could work in some instances, and not in others. You would have to check the compiler's documentation.

Comment: Oddly this does work `y ^= x1 ^= y; x1 ^= y;`.  So one level of "stacking" is OK , but more isn't?  Yes this is all horrible code, but also horribly interesting.

Comment: @juharr: I'm not sure about the rules in C#, but in C++, modifying and using `y` is still not valid.

Comment: @rcgldr: With optimisation? In all cases, regardless of what code is around it (e.g. if the compiler is running low on registers, if `x` and `y` are array elements [`arr[x] ^= arr[y] ...`], and so on? It is undefined by the standard. Undefined does not guarantee ANYTHING, which includes "it does what you expect", "it sometimes does what you expect, depending on circumstances", "the code crashes", "hard disk becomes formatted", "nuclear war starts" - and all those are valid for the same compiler and the same source code.

Comment: The issue is related to [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point). Since associativity and order of evaluation for the operator ^= is specified to be right to left in C / C++, it's a grey area, since ^= also stores the result. Apparently in C#, the storage of results is not occurring during the execution of the one line xor swap.

Answer (score 1):

```
int X = 3;
X = X + X++; // X = 6;

int X = 3
X = X++ + X; // X = 7;
```

Similarly:

```
int X = 3;
int Y = 5;
X = (Y ^= X ^= Y)^X; // X = 5
```

However:

```
int X = 3;
int Y = 5;
X = X^(Y ^= X ^= Y); // X = 0
```

Unfortunately:

`X = X^(Y ^= X ^= Y)` is an equivalence of  `X ^= Y ^= X ^= Y`

Answer (score 0):

I checked the MSIL generated by the compiler. In the first case, everything is normal - push x, push y, xor, pop x etc.
In the 2nd case it starts with push x, push y, push x, push y and ends up using the initial value of x in the last xor:

```
ldloc.0
ldloc.1
ldloc.0
ldloc.1
xor
dup
stloc.0
xor
dup
stloc.1
xor
dup
stloc.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried generating ASM of C++ code and decompiling the .NET code here is what I got:

**ASM**

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR _X$[ebp]
mov ecx, DWORD PTR _Y$[ebp]
mov edx, DWORD PTR [eax]
xor edx, DWORD PTR [ecx]
mov eax, DWORD PTR _X$[ebp]
mov DWORD PTR [eax], edx
mov ecx, DWORD PTR _Y$[ebp]
mov edx, DWORD PTR _X$[ebp]
mov eax, DWORD PTR [ecx]
xor eax, DWORD PTR [edx]
mov ecx, DWORD PTR _Y$[ebp]
mov DWORD PTR [ecx], eax
mov edx, DWORD PTR _X$[ebp]
mov eax, DWORD PTR _Y$[ebp]
mov ecx, DWORD PTR [edx]
xor ecx, DWORD PTR [eax]
mov edx, DWORD PTR _X$[ebp]
mov DWORD PTR [edx], ecx
```

from my little knowledge of assembly I think that this basically is:

```
X ^= Y;
Y ^= X;
X ^= Y;
```

**C#** (Generated with JetBrains dotPeek)

```
int& local1 = @X;
int num1 = ^local1;
int& local2 = @Y;
int num2 = ^local2;
int num3 = X ^= Y;
int num4;
int num5 = num4 = num2 ^ num3;
^local2 = num4;
int num6 = num5;
int num7 = num1 ^ num6;
^local1 = num7;
```

Not sure of the meaning of `&,^,@`, but I think that this is basically:

```
int xStartingValue = X;
X ^= Y;
Y ^= X;
X = xStartingValue ^ Y;
```